# Make a Stream of arrays of elements from one array of these elements is not possible in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Given the fragment code:

```
    Integer [] arrayIntegers_1 = {100,5,80,9,65,200};
    Integer [] arrayIntegers_2 = {30,99,800};
    Integer [] arrayIntegers_3 = {166,520,7};

    Stream<Integer[]> streamOfArraysOfIntegers=Stream.of(arrayIntegers_1,arrayIntegers_2,arrayIntegers_3);
    //OK, it is a Stream of arrays of Integers

    Stream<Integer[]> streamOfArraysOfIntegers_1=Stream.of(arrayIntegers_1);
    //Compilation fail in this line, Java cannot make a Stream of arrays of Integers or others objects from one (1) array

    Stream<Integer> streamOfOfIntegers=Stream.of(arrayIntegers_1);
    //From one (1) array Java makes a Stream of elements in this array, in this case it is a Stream of Integers
```

In the line with fail compilation, I waited Java makes a Stream of arrays of Integers with one array of Integers, but not.  In the next line, We can see Java makes a Stream of Integers from one array.

However, with the Collections doesn´t happen that, how we can see in the next fragment code, last line,

```
    ArrayList<Integer> listOfIntegers=new ArrayList<>();
    listOfIntegers.add(300); listOfIntegers.add(5); listOfIntegers.add(98); listOfIntegers.add(1); listOfIntegers.add(7);
    ArrayList<Integer> listOfIntegers_1=new ArrayList<>();
    listOfIntegers_1.add(999); listOfIntegers_1.add(3); listOfIntegers_1.add(85);   listOfIntegers_1.add(561); listOfIntegers_1.add(42);

    Stream<ArrayList<Integer>> streamOfListofIntegers=Stream.of(listOfIntegers,listOfIntegers_1);
    Stream<ArrayList<Integer>> streamOfListofIntegers_1=Stream.of(listOfIntegers); //Stream of ArrayList of Integers with one (1) ArrayList of Integers
```

I`d thank any comment.

Comment: from the java doc `Returns a sequential ordered stream whose elements are the specified values`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to force `Stream.of` to build a `Stream<Integer[]>`, you can use:

```
Stream<Integer[]> streamOfArraysOfIntegers_1 = 
                     Stream.<Integer[]>of(arrayIntegers_1);
```

The reason is that `Stream.of` takes a var-arg, which means it makes a stream of individual elements of that array when given a single array.

You wouldn't need to do that if you actually pass it multiple arrays:

```
Stream<Integer[]> streamOfArraysOfIntegers_1 = 
                     Stream.of(arrayIntegers_1, arrayIntegers_2);
```

The comparison of this behavior to that of collections is not relevant. This affects arrays because they have a relationship with var-args (You can pass `T[]` as argument to a method that has `T...` as parameter); and that is not the case for collections.

Comment: I believe such construct is called a *type witness*.

Comment: @MCEmperor That's what I also know it as. I just don't think I've ever read that in official docs :-)

Comment: Me neither, but it seems that the term comes from [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) apparently :-).